# How do I create and link to a category section in my templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, categories

I am new to django and I have tried a few suggestions but can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to create a blog post model with a category section and link to the categories in my template. My codes are as follows.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


# Create your models here.

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class MoneyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MoneyManager, self).get_queryset().filter(category='money')


class LoveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(LoveManager, self).get_queryset().filter(category='love')


class WeightlossManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(WeightlossManager, self).get_queryset().filter(category='weightloss')


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('money', 'Money'),
        ('love', 'Love'),
        ('weightloss', 'Weightloss')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='get_image_filename', verbose_name='Image', blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='get_image_filename', verbose_name='Image', blank=True)
    body2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='get_image_filename', verbose_name='Image', blank=True)
    body3 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    money = MoneyManager()
    love = LoveManager()
    weightloss = WeightlossManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
        4e2
        aaefb22cf2adc42680d
        ' -H '
        Content - Type: multipart / form - data
        ' -POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/scan_binary/   -F binary_file=@/Users/a.b.gopalakrishna/Desktop/tele.apk -F uuid=a996a142e1ef4a6e9e29dd7f6baf120bfsfds
```

I want to have a section in my templates called category that will display 3 categories (money, love and weightloss).

How do I go about it and how do I code the template to display this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_meta.get_field.("category").choices` or `get_category_display` for doing that or you can convert directly field choice `CATEGORY_CHOICES` on a `dict` so like:

```
  def convert_dict_choice(self):
            category_dict = dict(self.CATEGORY_CHOICES)
            return category_dict
```

Thus, you can call on your `view` y pass it as context on your `response`for your template, so like:

```
  def select_options(request):
    category_select = Post().convert_dict_choice()
    return render(
        request, "template/name_template.html",        
        {"data_select":category_select}
    )
```

Then, the template you can do so like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="category">
        <h1>Seccion category</h1>
        <select name="services" id="services">
            {% for category_selectvice in data_select %}
                    <option>{{category_selectvice}}</option>      
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

If you wish more reference visit the doc of django [Doc django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).